# Should all dependencies be loaded on every request?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, silex

Hello I am making a PHP application using Silex and I want to use Dependency Injection. For Dependency Injection I need to load the dependencies into the container. I have one file that contains all definitions of what to load into the container called di.php it looks like this.

```
/**
 * DI.php
 */
$app['db.connection'] = function() use($app) {
    return new Connection([
        'dbname' => $app['dbname'],
        'dbuser' => $app['dbuser'],
        'dbpass' => $app['dbpass'],
        'dbhost' => $app['dbhost'],
    ]);
};

$app['user.repository'] = function() use($app) {
    return new UserRepository($app['db.connection']);
};

$app['post.repository'] = function() use($app) {
    return new PostRepository($app['db.connection']);
};    

$app['index.controller'] = function() use($app) {
    return new IndexController($app['user.repository']);
};

$app['post.controller'] = function() use($app) {
    return new PostController($app['post.repository']);
};
```

But this file is requested on every request and all dependencies are loaded into the container, my question is how can I load the dependencies that I only need for one request and not all.

Comment: You're defining callback functions which return those object instances *when called*. I don't know about Silex, but unless somebody calls those functions, the objects won't be loaded/instantiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @deceze says in their comment (shoulda made it an answer!), all you are "loading" on each request is a bunch of function expression statements. You can basically look at your providers as "classes" wherein the function declarations are done as function expressions rather than function statements. As per a normal class, the functions don't *run* simply cos you define them, right? No. You need to actually call them before they do anything.

The code within the function expression assigned to the `$app['db.connection']` service is only executed *if you use* `$app['db.connection']`. Otherwise all you've done is defined a variable holding a function.

Obviously in the case of `$app['db.connection']` you *are* more than likely gonna be using it every request one way or another. But for argument's sake `$app['post.repository']` will only have its callback executed if you actively use `$app['post.repository']` in that request.

Make sense? I can elaborate further if not.